# Why Don't I Get Credit for Answering Tester Questions Ensuring I Am Paying Attention?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

When reviewing questions in Triage, every once in awhile SO throws a "tester" question to see if the user is actually paying attention.
I get why they are doing it, and I'm not complaining about it, but it still takes time for the user to assess the question, and make a sound judgement.

I'm not so much whining about not getting points, nor am I 100% on getting full points for correctly completing the task, but the question remains: how is it ok to waste the user's time in order to validate they are taking the question(s) seriously?
Why don't we get credit (in some form) for answering them correctly?
What is my motivation when some of my time is wasted?

EDIT: Why was this down voted?

Comment: i mean... i'd expect *not* being banned by performing the correct action good enough motivation.

Comment: why would a user be banned for correctly answering questions

Comment: *I get why they are doing it* - If you know why audits exist, why do you still consider it a waste of time?

Comment: These are called "review audits" by the way. Let's also note that it is usually _insanely_ easy to spot audits, so making rewards for passing them... Is likely going to be a horrible idea.

Comment: easy is relative to each person. whats easy for you is not necessarily easy to others.

Comment: @BSMP great point. asking this and getting these responses has had the enlightened effect i was hoping for. i guess i was conflating them? not sure, but do see your point.

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).  Down votes are often used to indicate disagreement.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> how is it ok to waste the user's time in order to validate they are taking the question(s) seriously?

Two words: robo reviewers.

If we did not have audits there would be so much stuff that gets through that shouldn't because you just have people farming badges.  The audits are there to promote quality which is what Stack Overflow is all about.  We want to be a repository for high quality question and answers.

> Why don't we get credit (in some form) for answering them correctly?

Do you really need credit?  You already get badges from completing reviews and audits count for that.  So in a sense you actually do get extra credit.  If you were a bad reviewer and get yourself banned from reviewing by failing audits you would not get the badges.